# android webview emulator not loading images and javascript

Tags: android, webview

I have the HTML file in the assets folder and trying to load that in android webview. The css style is not getting applied also javascript isnt getting applied and images are not getting loaded.
Here is the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView ctWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ctWebview);
        ctWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        ctWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ctWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        ctWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        ctWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                Log.e("resource",url);
            }
        });
        ctWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/creditrackerhtml.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/ctWebview"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The HTML file is too big to paste here, but I have put the logs in public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)  and have seen that proper resource urls are being hit at.
Is it that webview is being loaded before the resources are downloaded? Not sure how to fix this problem

Comment: Check your logcat please. It should give some sort of info regarding what's  not setup properly. Better post if there's anything here.

Comment: There is no issue that I see in logcat, it is hitting the resource URLs but webview is getting loaded before the resources are loaded

Comment: Are you sure the resources that need to be loaded are linked correctly to the HTML file? The paths have to be relative.

Comment: I have a base tag like <base href="https://creditscore.capitalone.com/web"/> and the images are loaded <div id="loader"><p>Loading...</p><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" style="width:64px;height:64px;"/></div>

Comment: Well before anything I guess then you should check and confirm if that tag is supported by the Android WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in assets folder.

Go to Project > app > src > main > right click > New > Folder > Assets Folder. Name it assets.

To access file use getAssets().open(filename.txt)

To make file to URL use file.toURI() or file.toURI().toURL().

Also, you do not need much to load url. Just use  webView.loadUrl(url);

If you have links use :

```
        //So links stay inside webview
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webview.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `loadDataWithBaseURL()`?

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url, 
        data,
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        null);
```

Because according to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)),

> loadDataWithBaseURL()
>   loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL
>   for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs
>   and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy. The historyUrl is
>   used for the history entry.

Comment: I have tried that, and used remote debugger and have seen the error messages as failed to load resources for CSS, images and JS. But those URLS were accessible from emulator's browser too. These are https resources

Answer (score 0):

The CSS and images in the HTML should use URLs relative to the assets directory or use absolute paths on the web.